# Best tool to build an intranet with low devops/database skills?

Tags: ide, web, nosql, go, intranet

I'm willing to build a webapp (intranet style) with very basic features : identification, data manipulation / visualisation, file upload/download, etc.

I'm a software developer (Golang mainly, but also C/C++/Python) and I had some minor projects in PHP/javascript too. I have zero skills in sysadmin, cloud, devops and so on. I have very elementary skills with databases.

What would you recommend as turnkey tool to built it without having to deep-dive into devops/database skills ? A fully online tool providing online IDE/preview, a database overlay and a builtin scalability would be awesome.

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest taking a look at [Anvil](https://anvil.works/) which is a paid *(but with free options)* development and hosting service with the following features:

- Web Based IDE
- Drag & Drop UI Builder
- Python based code in both browser & server
- Built in Database with python access
- One Click Cloud Deployment
- Built-in user authentication
- On Site (paid) or Open Source Server
- Lots of helpful tutorials & videos